# Bidirectional One-To-Many

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create a bidirectional One-To-Many relation in Doctrine 2.1. I Compared my code to the [manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-associations.html) and to other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328836/problem-understanding-relation-mapping-in-doctrine-2) but still can't see what I am doing wrong. I only get a blank screen so it's hard to debug. (log_threshold = 4 but no error in the log).

I have those two tables:

**user**

```
id
name
```

**cart**

```
id
items
```

And here are my two models (in short):

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Cart", mappedBy="user_id")
     */
    private $carts;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="cart")
 */
class Cart
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="carts")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

Then I try to link them

```
$user = $this->em->find('models\User', 8);

$cart = new models\Cart();
$user->getCarts()->add($cart);
$cart->setOwner($user);

$this->em->persist($cart);
$this->em->flush();
```

Here I get a blank screen.
Without One-To-Many it works fine.

Comment: `$user->getCarts()->add($cart);` will not work. You have to create a method addCart() in the User entity

Comment: Yes sure, I have getCarts() and setOwner(). Works fine without the em->flush().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself. The trick was to show error messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

I needed to fill some fields with values. There were not allowed to be null. DOH!