# Doctrine launches INSERT always instead of UPDATE for existing entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Let's say I have the following entities:

App\Entity\MainEntity:

```
  /**
   * @var object
   *
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\DependentEntity", fetch="EAGER")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DependentEntityType1FK", referencedColumnName="DependentEntityIDPK")
   */
  private $dependentEntityType1;

  /**
   * @var object
   *
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\DependentEntity", fetch="EAGER")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DependentEntityType2FK", referencedColumnName="DependentEntityIDPK")
   */
  private $dependentEntityType2;
```

Basically, one-directional 1:1 relationship from main entity to the same dependent entity using two different columns in the main entity table.

It doesn't matter, whether I use `fetch="EAGER"` or normal lazy loading through Doctrine proxy classes, when I do something like this:

```
  $mainEntity = $this->mainEntityRepository->find(74);
  $mainEntity->setDependentEntityType1($this->dependentEntityRepository->find(35));
  $this->mainEntityRepository->saveTest($mainEntity);
```

where `::saveTest()` is:

```
  public function saveTest(MainEntity $mainEntity) {
    $this->_em->persist($mainEntity->getDependentEntityType1());
    $this->_em->merge($mainEntity);
    $this->_em->flush();
  }
```

it always tries to INSERT a new dependent entity to the table, even though I never made any changes (and even if I made them, it should have been UPDATE! for it)

The question is: why does Doctrine decide this dependent entity is a new one if I did `$this->dependentEntityRepository->find(35)` , so loaded an existing one?

I tried `fetch="EAGER"` thinking that `spl_object_hash` might return different hashes for a Proxy class instance and the actual DependantEntity one, but it doesn't matter, the DependantEntity is for some reason *always* considered as "new".

**UPDATE:** here is the code of `::setDependentEntityType1()`

```
  public function setDependentEntityType1(DependentEntity $dependentEntity) : void {
    $this->dependentEntity = $dependentEntity;
  }
```

Comment: [Owning](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) Side? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346233/what-is-the-owning-side-and-inverse-side-in-the-doctrine-2-doc-example

Comment: Thanks @ficuscr! The problem is this is a unidirectional relationship, so the dependent entity doesn't have a column with `main_enttity_id`, we don't need a property in it to contain a reference to the main entity and therefore I can't place anything into `inversedBy` of the owning (main entity) side

Comment: Awesome. Smelled familiar but got sleepy reading the docs (ORMs do that to me)  so I didn't want to wager an answer. Glad you made sense of it!

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, I meant thanking for your comment :) but the problem is still there. I just explained I cannot put anything into inversedBy as there is nothing in the dependent entities pointing to the main one as it's unidirectional mapping

Comment: *Whoosh*. See what I meant :) Can you shed more light on what the function `setDependentEntityType1` does? Something seems weird here. I've never once written anything like this in Doctrine. FYI `merge` is supposed to be removed in [Doctrine3](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/UPGRADE.md).

Comment: sure, see my update. `merge()` call was just a test in hundreds of other attempts. I can remove it, replace with `persist()` , but the problem recognizing existing dependent entity as "new" remains :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198971/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-alexey).