# doctrine: refers to owning side field which does not exist (again)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Can't wrap my head around it. I more or less copied from the tutorial, but the profiler throws two errors:

> AppBundle\Entity\Brand The association AppBundle\Entity\Brand#devices
>   refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\Device#brands which
>   does not exist.
>
> AppBundle\Entity\Device The association AppBundle\Entity\Device#brand
>   refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Brand#brands which
>   does not exist.

```
class Brand {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Device", mappedBy="brands")
     */
    private $devices;
}
```

and

```
class Device {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="devices")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $brand;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but according to docs, it should look something like this

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

```
class Brand {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="brand_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Device", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    private $devices;
}
```

and

```
class Device {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="devices")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $brand;
}
```

Comment: well huh! you're right! so the inversedBy and mappedBy values are not table names?

Comment: No, it's internal doctrine thing, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/34583366/3275814

Answer (score 1):

Defining the associations as private wasn't working but once I changed them to protected, it worked. Though the most important thing to note is that the associations defined in your classes is what should be used in the inversedby and mappedby attributes and not the class name or table name. Here is a useful post: [What is the difference between inversedBy and mappedBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493865/what-is-the-difference-between-inversedby-and-mappedby/34583366#)