# Doctrine Self-referencing Association Mapping (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, associations

I want to create a FAQ System, where the admin is able to create another FAQ in the FAQ a SubFAQ in the FAQ and so on..

I know that I need to self-reference, but how could I solve this?

My Entity FAQ.php looks like this:

```
 /**
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Faq", mappedBy="parent")
  */
 private $children;

 /**
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Faq", inversedBy="children")
 * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
 private $parent;

 public function __construct() {
   $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
 }
```

What I don't understand is the inversedBy and how to use all this.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493865/what-is-the-difference-between-inversedby-and-mappedby#12495834 may help.

Comment: Also http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping .

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add some methods to add SubFAQs and return all SubFAQs.

```
/**
 * @param Faq $child
 *
 * @return Faq
 */
public function addSubFAQ($child)
{
    $this->children[] = $child;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getSubFAQs()
{
    return $this->children;
}
```